# jquery change section with scrolling and animation

Tags: jquery, css, html

I need a scroll code sample that can be changed section by scrolling down and above it.And I don't want to give specific height for  sections.

Comment: Please read 'how to ask a good question' - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different ways to get X and Y.

1. screenX, screenY: total monitor width/height.
2. pageX, pageY: browser size.
3. clientX, clientY: the area that the client is seeing.

   ```
   $(window).bind('mousemove', function( event ) {
       var screenCoords = "( " + event.screenX + ", " + event.screenY + " )";
       var pageCoords = "( " + event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY + " )";
       var clientCoords = "( " + event.clientX + ", " + event.clientY + " )";
       console.log("global", "event.screenX, event.screenY ) : " + screenCoords );
       console.log("global", "event.pageX, event.pageY ) : " + pageCoords );
       console.log("global", "event.clientX, event.clientY ) : " + clientCoords );});
   ```

screen:

[image]

page & client:

[image]